# Implementation of hashCode and equals in int[] Java

Tags: java

It looks like the hashCode() and equals() for int[] are poorly implemented, or not implemented at all! 
(Tested with Android, but I expect it to be true for any Java environment).

In order to get  HashSet.contains() working properly, I had to create a wrapper for int[] (plse, don't criticize my coding style, look at the essence):

```
public class IntArray {
    private int[] value;

    public IntArray(int[] value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int sum = 0;
        // Integer overflows are cheerfully welcome.
        for (int elem: value) sum += elem;
        return sum;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) return (value==null);

        if (value != null) {
            if (o instanceof int[]) 
                return compare((int[])o);

            if (o instanceof IntArray)
                return compare(((IntArray)o).value);
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected boolean compare(int[] other) {
        int len = value.length;
        if (other.length != len) return false;
        for (int i=0; i<len ; i++)
            if (value[i] != other[i]) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Works OK, but I prefer to avoid a custom wrapper or a third-party library. Is there an option?

Comment: "*hashCode() and equals() for int[] are poorly implemented, or not implemented at all*"  Care to elaborate?

Comment: hashCode and equals for arrays essentially default to the implementation in Object, which will only find an object equal to itself.  This isn't "poorly implemented" and certainly it's not "not implemented at all", it's implemented as defined.  However, you are correct that the situation is not, shall we say, "satisfying".

Comment: Isn't `ArrayList<Integer>` the wrapper you are looking for?

Comment: By "poorly implemented" I mean implemented illogically, which may cause  problems, like the one we have. You wouldn't be pleased if String class were implemented by leaving hashCode() and equals() to default. Why int[] should be worse?

Comment: It's not "implemented illogically".  The implementation for arrays is the default implementation for Object, plain and simple.  Among other things, using a more "logical" implementation would mean that hashCode would perform *much* worse, and often in cases where there is no benefit to the "more logical" behavior.  Java could have defined "deepEquals" and "deepHashCode" methods on Object that would maybe make this all better, but they could have defined hundreds of things they did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the standard Java Hashtable does not allow an override of the hash code used for keys, you are out of luck and will need to use a wrapper like you did.

keep in mind that your hashCode implementation is very bad, you can use this (Taken from java.util.Arrays in the standard JDK) to get a better hash distrubtion:

```
public static int hashCode(int a[]) {
  if (a == null)
    return 0;

  int result = 1;
  for (int element : a)
    result = 31 * result + element;
  return result;
}
```

An alternative is to use a different Hashtable, which can deal with primitives.
one such option is [Banana](https://github.com/omry/banana), which is a primitive collections library I created.

Comment: Thanks, indeed this method provide a more sporadic distribution of hash values. Probably 31 is used as a prime number, but for efficiency (especially with Android) in may be better using a power of 2 with left shift instead of multiplication.

Comment: yes, 31 is chosen specifically because it's prime.
power of two shifts will probably give much worse distribution, and its unlikely that this will be the thing that will slow you down.

Answer (score 0):

After Omry Yadan's message the hashCode function becomes as simple as that!

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(value);
    }
```

For a RISC CPU, like ARM, It may be more efficient:

```
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int code = 0;
        if (value != null) {
            code++;
            for (int elem: value)
                code = (code<<5) - code + elem;
        }
        return code;
    }
```

May be there is also a standard function for comparing arrays, in which case equals() can be simplified too?

Comment: Arrays.asList( value ).compareTo( Arrays.asList( other ) )